# Search object a element and return the element and parents

Tags: json, typescript

I want to make a search from object JSON but when a I found the element I want to be returned with his previous parents.

```js
 [
  {
    "name": "level1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "level2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "level3a",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text",
                "more": "info"
              },
              {
                "name": "text Abc",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "level3b",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text-C",
                "more": "info"
              },
              {
                "name": "search",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "level3c",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "info-C",
                "more": "info"
              },
              {
                "name": "search",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "level1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "level2a",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "level3",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text A",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "level2b",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "level3",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text X",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For example: if want to search "text" I want result like this

```js
[
  {
    "name": "level1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "level2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "level3a",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text",
                "more": "info"
              },
              {
                "name": "text Abc",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "level3b",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text-C",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "level1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "level2a",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "level3",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text A",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "level2b",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "level3",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "text X",
                "more": "info"
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Things to considerer

1. only "search" in level 3 children by name property
2. if one o more childrens matches the search, return all of them

Basically I need to filter by the last level of object with elements matches with the search and return them with them parents.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WP7LEm) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: yes! this helps me a lot! there is a way to use this but for all the childrens? for example if the last children has name value "text" and the other "text A" and im looking for "text" matches return both

Comment: Is this a followup question or was that part of the original requirement?  If it's a followup question it probably needs its own post.  If it was part of the original requirement, then I'm confused: your own input example had a `"textA"` value but you didn't want it to be in the output when looking for `"text"`; why?  Please [edit] your question to specify exactly what the requirements are, and maybe I can write an algorithm that works for it.

Comment: update question

Comment: Hmm, now I'm more confused than I was before.  Why would you want to hardcode "level 3"?  Your data is formatted in a way that makes it hard to understand; you might want to use code blocks and indentation to make the structure apparent.

Comment: i updated the question with a better format!